# Rewrite condition "if cookie is not set" - redirect to mobile site (in combination with jquery mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile, redirect, apache2, typo3

I want to redirect smartphone users by a rewrite rule from the classic site to my mobile site (in the same domain). At the mobile site there should be a button, which redirects to the classic site. This should be realized by a rewrite condition, which prooves, if there was set a cookie. So I wrote the following .htaccess:

```
# Rewrite Condititions
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
# Do not rewrite when cookie is set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*backtoclassic.*$
# Rewrite Rule for mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?id=104 [L,R=301]
# End rule for mobile
```

The mobile site (../index.php?id=104) works with jquery mobile. I putted off ajax. The "back-to-classic-site-button" gets his cookie named "backtoclassic" by the following code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(e,data){    
  ...
  ...
  $(document).on('click', '#classicsite',function(e) {
    $.cookie('backtoclassic', 'backtoclassic');
  });
});
```

The button itself has the following code in the setup of typo3:

```
### Back-to-Classic-Site ###
lib.classic = TEXT
lib.classic.value = <a href="/" rel="external" data-role="button">back</a>
```

Of course I proved, if the cookie is set correctly when I click on the button; this works so far. But, the problem is the following: When I click on the button, the cookie is set and the browser (in this case safari on iphone) tries to go to the classic site. But then I get redirected to the mobile site again. When I type in the url in safari "manually", then at the first try I also get redirected to the mobile site. When I type in the classic url **second time** it works an I reach the classic site!! This is strange...
Then I tried the following: I deleted the http_user_agent-condition and tried it not with the mobile site but with another site of my classic site. There the "non-jquery-"link works. So I think maybe it has something to do with jquery/jquery mobile? 
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Risking some downvotes here, but don't do "classic/mobile" sites, use RWD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

It solves many problems that occur with the multiple-sites-approach

Comment: I don't want to use responsive design. I solved the problem by setting the link by a funktion in typo3, so the rewrite rule/rewrite condition and the java-script were correct.